# Bash отслеживание вывода

Tags: bash

Я сделал бесконечный цикл в `Bash` скрипте на перезапуск стриминга.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
  do
    ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://{address:port}/{key}" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -c:a libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -c:v copy -threads 2 -bufsize 512k -f flv "rtmps://{address:port}/live/{key}" &
    PID=$!
    sleep 12h
    kill $PID
    sleep 2
 done
```

Но иногда возникает ошибка... которая выводится в консоли в следующем виде:

```
rtsp://{address:port}/{key}: Invalid date found when processing input
```

И это время стрим не работает. Как дополнить мой скрипт, что бы отслеживалось после запуска команды вывод в консоли и при появлении ошибки **`Invalid date found when processing input`** заканчивался процесс и сразу же перезапускал стрим?

Comment: Ну если прямо в лоб, то добавьте проверку существования процесса после запуска, скажем, через 30 секунд.

Comment: @0andriy а можно пример того как это сделать, пожалуйста?)